# Updating data to SQLITE database

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-update

Im trying to update some data in my sqlite database in Xcode, however it keeps failing. Here is my code.

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Cant find users db to save data");
}else{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_usersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE users SET companyname = \'%@\', companyaddress = \'%@\', companycity = \'%@\', companystate = \'%@\', companyzip = \'%@\', companyphone = \'%@\', companyfax = \'%@\', companyemail = \'%@\', companywebsite = \'%@\', driverfirstname = \'%@\', driverlastname = \'%@\', driveraddress = \'%@\', drivercity = \'%@\', driverstate = \'%@\', driverzip = \'%@\', driverphone = \'%@\', driverfax = \'%@\', driveremail = \'%@\', driverwebsite = \'%@\', WHERE user = \'%@\'",
                              self.companyName.text,
                              self.companyAddress.text,
                              self.companyCity.text,
                              self.companyState.text,
                              self.companyZip.text,
                              self.companyPhone.text,
                              self.companyFax.text,
                              self.companyEmail.text,
                              self.companyWebsite.text,
                              self.driverFirstName.text,
                              self.driverLastName.text,
                              self.driverAddress.text,
                              self.driverCity.text,
                              self.driverState.text,
                              self.driverZip.text,
                              self.driverPhone.text,
                              self.driverFax.text,
                              self.driverEmail.text,
                              self.driverWebsite.text,
                              [[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_usersDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Updated user in db");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to update user in db");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_usersDB);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where Im going wrong. My code keeps making it to the "Failed to update user in db" NSLog statement at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not build your query using `stringWithFormat`. Do it properly using the proper `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: Why are you calling `sqlite3_finalize` before preparing the statement? Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, I will convert to the bind function if thats the proper way, but it should still work as is, right? Not sure how I missed the finalize statement, I removed it but it still fails.

Comment: Until you log `sqlite3_errmsg` when the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, no one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

If either `sqlite3_prepare_v2` or `sqlite3_step` fails, you should call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get a useful error message.

(And that message would tell you that the WHERE is invalid after the surplus comma.)

Comment: CL, i noticed the surplus comma after I posted, but that didnt resolve the issue. I will try the errmsg in a bit to get a more detailed response. Thanks.

Comment: Finally got a chance to use the errmsg and I figured out the issue.  The db was locked because I had used a connection earlier that I didn't close.  Thanks CL.  Haven't used sqlite in the past but now I know about the errmsg option for future issues.